# Angular Parent component not listening to child event

Tags: angular9

I'm new to Angular 9.

I'm trying to propagate events from child to parent, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as the parent doesn't get the event at all.

**Here is my child cmp html**

```
<a (click)="view(profilo.id)" class="btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon like"></a>
```

**child ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gestione-profili',
  templateUrl: './gestione-profili.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gestione-profili.component.scss']
})
export class GestioneProfiliComponent implements OnInit {
@Output() vedi = new EventEmitter<string>(); 
id=0;
view(id){
  //console.log(id+'figlio')
  this.id = id;
  this.informazioni=true;
 this.vedi.emit(id);
}
}
```

**And here my parent html**

```
<app-gestione-profili (vedi)="mostra($event)"></app-gestione-profili>
```

**And parent Ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pannello-controllo',
  templateUrl: 'pannello-controllo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pannello-controllo.component.scss']
})
export class PannelloControlloComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  id=0;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  mostra(id){
    this.id=id;
    console.log(id+ 'padre')
  }
}
```

Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: where you get the variable `profilo.id` ? `profilo` is undefined that why you don't have result

Comment: In the posted code the `profilo` attribute is not present in child ts, and the same happens with the `ngOnInit()` method. If you implement `OnInit` you must define it. Try to fix this things and check if the error persist.

Comment: Is the view() method in the child getting executed? Is the mostra() method on the parent getting executed? Can you console.log(id) in the mostra() method and display the output?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was my stupid mistake...I didn't add the route for parent component in app-routing--so the html never got read and the event never propagate--
I've solved it just by adding the path in app-routing
thanks to all of you anyway